# Java generic warning while using Spring Environment.getProperty() to get a list

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables

It might be a question with no answer as java generic warnings are tough to get rid of, but want to give it a try.
We are migrating from Spring 2.x to 3.x, so converting our Spring XML into Spring Java based configuration. While doing that we started using Environment to get a List of Strings.

So, the XML was like this:

```
<bean id="test" class="ClassName">
     <constructor-arg index="0" value ="value1,value2,value3" />
</bean>
```

Now, spring obviously converts the constructor argument into a List and passes it to the constructor.

But, now we are using Java based configuration using Environment.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public ClassName getBean() {
    List<String> strings = env.getProperty("prop.values", List.class);
    return new ClassName(strings);
}
```

Now obviously I have to put @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") on the method as this line generates the warning...

```
List<String> strings = env.getProperty("prop.values", List.class);
```

Since we inject lists in many places while constructing beans, people are complaining about this and unwilling to use Java based configuration.

There may not be a way to suppress this warning, if not, is there any better way to do this in Spring that doesn't generate warnings like this? Thanks.

Comment: Just because you can use Spring's Java configuration, doesn't mean you have to.

Comment: Can you give an example of your `ClassName` constructor and the value of the `prop.values` property?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I understand your point. If there is no better way, we probably will mix some xml with java configs. Just want to make sure before we rule out. As an example, just imagine any simple class that takes List<String> as one argument in the constructor. nothing serious.

Comment: You can create the `List` yourself by splitting the `String` returned by `env.getProperty("prop.values")` and adding the array elements to a `List`.

Comment: Well, thats the point, its boiler plate stuff, i thought spring is smart enough to provide things like that. People moving from Xml to Java configs don't like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you pulling things from the `Environment` manually? Spring is a dependency injection framework; environment values can also be injected!

Try this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Value("${prop.values}")
    private List<String> strings;

    @Bean
    public ClassName test() {
        return new ClassName(strings);
    }
}
```

Or, better yet, just use component scanning. That way you can do away with the `@Bean` method entirely and leave even more heavy lifting to Spring.

```
@Component("test")
public ClassName {

    private List<String> strings;

    public ClassName(@Value("${prop.values}") List<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }

}

@Component
public class MyClassThatUsesClassNameBean {

    @Autowired
    private ClassName test;
}
```